# Partial template specialization, using a templatized type (nested template classes)

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Given the generic function foo:

```
template<typename T> void foo(T a) { a(); }
```

I'd like to specialize this function for a type Bar, however, Bar itself has several template arguments itself.
I was trying to specialize foo() as follows:

```
template<typename... Args> void foo<Bar<Args...> >(Bar<Args...> a) { a(42); }
```

However, this does not quite work. Could someone please help me out? Thanks

Comment: Make it `template<typename... Args> void foo(Bar<Args...> a) { a(42); }` , then you would have two overloaded function templates. This should work; the one taking `Bar` should be chosen by overload resolution as more specialized, when the argument is in fact a `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

There ain't no such thing as a partial specialization of a function template. One way around is to delegate to a class template, which can in fact be partially specialized. Something along these lines:

```
template <typename T>
struct FooImpl {
  static void foo(T a) { /* general implementation */ }
};

template<typename... Args>
struct FooImpl<Bar<Args...>> {
  static void foo(Bar<Args...> a) { /* special implementation */ }
};

template<typename T>
void foo(T a) { FooImpl<T>::foo(a); }
```

Comment: hmm.. I feel like use of operator() and CRTP may help?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `operator()` might be a good fit, but I don't see what a CRTP would bring to the table?

Comment: @Quentin if this thing is a recurring pattern, instead of constantly writing an operator () (or other interfaces), inherit one.